# C++ for loop too slow

Tags: c++, callback, portaudio

I'm trying to make an audio application with PortAudio. My callback function has been very slow and it has been creating constant underruns. I removed everything in the callback one by one until I found the issue: the for loop. I removed everything so that the only thing happening in the callback function is the for loop and it is still causing underruns. I know it is the for loop because when I reduce the number of iterations, the underruns go away.

```
static int patestCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                      unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                      const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                      PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int jj = 0; jj < 10000; jj++)
    {
        x++; // for testing, not actually used
    };
    return paContinue;
}
```

Here is my full code for testing: https://gist.github.com/johnroper100/b87641f5609dbb49bc3c1121b1f4daf1

Not really necessary for this question, but I did the same callback in the python equivalent (sounddevice) and there are no issues.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `for` loop completely?

Comment: It's... It's empty

Comment: How many times per second is this callback function called? Do you have compiler optimizations active?

Comment: If this is optimized the compiler will totally remove the loop. I am not sure your current code has nothing inside the loop.

Comment: Bathsheba: if I remove the for loop all together there are no more underruns.

Comment: @JohnRoper: That's odd indeed. What is `sizeof(PaStreamCallbackFlags)`? My instinct then is that there is a problem elsewhere in the program - perhaps you're leaking memory and / or threads.

Comment: My crystal ball says you are testing a unoptimized debug build (the default for most compilers) rather than a optimized release build...

Comment: @Bathsheba It gives me 8. I added a link to my full code in the question.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant but according to the documentation it seems like the callback function should take as little time as possible, and since you mention the reductions of iterations made the underruns disappear maybe it is related? [PortAudio Doc](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html)

Comment: You are not checking the return values of `sf_open`, `sf_command`, `sf_read_float` and `malloc`. Are you absolutely sure that all of these functions are succeeding and returning the value you expect?

Comment: Is the code snippet just for demonstration or that you have actually run? Asking because the return value is missing declaration and the code shouldn’t compile.

Comment: What makes you think that there are buffer underruns? Did you get an error message saying that? Or are you hearing audio glitches and assuming that these glitches must be caused by underruns?

Comment: @DXZ I believe the return value is an enum defined in the `portaudio.h`. Either `paContinue = 0`, `paComplete = 1` or `paAbort = 2`

Comment: It may help if you provided the full source code of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. The code you posted on StackOverflow is not reproducible and the code you posted on GibHub is not minimal, as it does extensive manipulation of the audio data(which does not seem necessary and may contain bugs). For the sake of a minimal reproducible example, you may want to consider generating the audio data algorithmically, for example by generating audio data with complete silence.

Comment: using ++jj instead of jj++ may help some depending on your compiler and if it replaced it for you, it would be a minimal speed increase but it's something

Comment: What are you randomly doing 10k iterations on? You can't ask people to optimize a loop and then not provide the loop that needs optimization.

Comment: To be 100% sure that this loop is really slowing down your code, just replace it with this: ```int x = 10000;``` and see if you have a considerable difference.

Comment: can you please provide the assembly result of both with and without the `for` loop?

Comment: @JohnRoper, I have been following this question for a bit because I found it interesting. Did any of the answers provide a solution, or havent you checked it yet?

Answer (score 6):

[From the API documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a8a60fb2a5ec9cbade3f54a9c978e2710):

> When a stream is running, PortAudio calls the stream callback periodically. The callback function is responsible for processing buffers of audio samples passed via the input and output parameters.
>
> The PortAudio stream callback runs at very high or real-time priority. It is required to consistently meet its time deadlines. Do not allocate memory, access the file system, call library functions or call other functions from the stream callback that may block or take an unpredictable amount of time to complete.
>
> **In order for a stream to maintain glitch-free operation the callback must consume and return audio data faster than it is recorded and/or played.** PortAudio anticipates that each callback invocation may execute for a duration approaching the duration of frameCount audio frames at the stream sample rate. It is reasonable to expect to be able to utilise 70% or more of the available CPU time in the PortAudio callback. However, due to buffer size adaption and other factors, not all host APIs are able to guarantee audio stability under heavy CPU load with arbitrary fixed callback buffer sizes. **When high callback CPU utilisation is required the most robust behavior can be achieved by using paFramesPerBufferUnspecified as the Pa_OpenStream() framesPerBuffer parameter.**

I highlighted the relevant part.

Comment: After reading the documentation I would agree with this answer, I was just not sure if this was what was asked about.

Comment: @darclander: The OP only provided incomplete information and also did not respond to several comments requesting clarification. Therefore, it is necessary for answers to guess what the problem might be. I think that this answer did this quite well.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel so answers on stackoverflow are allowed to be guessed if OP wont respond with enough clarification?

Comment: @darclander: Normally, such questions would be closed. However, it is not possible to flag a question for closure while it has an open bounty.

Answer (score 3):

A for loop with nothing in it is still hard work for you CPU.

If you don't want your CPU spending all its power on that for loop you should at least make that for loop contain something that gives up CPU cycles.

The simplest way would be to put a call to sleep() or nanosleep() in there.

More advanced would be to use threads with the proper mechanisms to make them wait for the required actions.

Comment: The function the OP posted is a [PortAudio callback function](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html) which is intended to be called every time new data is available or is needed. According to the documentatino of that function, it is likely that it is already being called by another thread, which is handled internally by PortAudio. Also, according to that documentation, you should not call any functions that cause context switches, such as `sleep`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel So then one should do these heavy calculations in another thread and  read calculated data in this callback. The other thread should have no such  restrictions (not call any functions that cause context switches).

Comment: @Oliort: This would require thread synchronization between the thread of the callback function and the worker thread. According to the PortAudio documentation in my link above, this is not recommended.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, maybe then one should use non-locking thread-synchronization primitives (atomic variables with compare-exchange mechanism). This also violates the "don't use anything that might rely on the OS", but the violation is the least possible in this case in my opinion. Also atomics are not included in that "do not use" list.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the reason to why the callback function is not working properly is explained by the documentation (in the answer @ÁdámHunyadi provided). But I am not sure if it explains *WHY* the for-loop is too slow.

> **In order for a stream to maintain glitch-free operation the callback
>   must consume and return audio data faster than it is recorded and/or
>   played.** PortAudio anticipates that each callback invocation may
>   **execute for a duration approaching the duration of frameCount audio
>   frames** at the stream sample rate. It is reasonable to expect to be
>   able to utilise 70% or more of the available CPU time in the PortAudio
>   callback. However, due to buffer size adaption and other factors, not
>   all host APIs are able to guarantee audio stability under heavy CPU
>   load with arbitrary fixed callback buffer sizes. **When high callback
>   CPU utilisation is required the most robust behavior can be achieved
>   by using paFramesPerBufferUnspecified as the Pa_OpenStream()
>   framesPerBuffer parameter.**

Looking at the example in the [PortAudio Doc Example](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html), they iterate through a `for-loop` of `framesPerBuffer` iteration (which in the docs are defined as `framesCount`). *Approaching the duration of frameCount*. But in your code example you are doing the same thing **BUT** you do it the size of a `vector` *times* (which I believe is not *Approaching the duration of frameCount*). Only using one `for-loop` instead of two, and using `framesPerBuffer` instead of `10000` as the maximum number of iterations might resolve the *"Too slow for-loop"* issue.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from API-specific questions that may cause your loops or overall program to slow down, I'll give a general advise to your general question. Always favor prefix (`++i;`) over postfix (`i++;`) increment if you'll ignore the returning value, because the prefix doesn't return the copy of the value/object you're applying the operator on. Hence, you can avoid an unnecessary copy operation. Although, most of the modern compilers do replace this for you on the fly, but they may be tricked with your code somehow, so it's always best to make it a habit to use prefix increment. And of course you need to compile your code with the `-O3` parameter for the highest performance and make sure the compiler will do its best. Another option to consider for optimizing loops further is multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code that capture a new frame is called after patestCallback ends, if you aren't able to meet your deadlines it means your CPU isn't powerful enough (=processing is too complex). This is not an explanation (of why) but a solutions that should work if you would have had more than one Core in your CPU (sometimes it works even if you have one Core), you could create a thread that process the audio, the callback should only copy (or change a pointer) to audio to be processed, which enables your main thread (audio capturing thread) to not wait too long.